# Does cmake has an option to avoid using undefined variables (like bash set-u)

Tags: cmake

Does `cmake` have a mechanism to generate an error when using a undefined variable, a bit like `set -u` option in `bash`.

I have a big project composed of several `CMakeLists.txt` files, representing ~1500 lines, so it is quite difficult to use this construction: `if(NOT DEFINED VAR_NAME)`

In a ideal world, the following `CMakeLists.txt` whould fail.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
message(STATUS "Will delete ${DIR}/${FILE}")
```

- Does such option exist? (I don't think so, but the `cmake` documentation is huge, I may have missed it)
- Is such behavior on the project roadmap?

Comment: I am not aware about such option in CMake. Actually some modules shipped with CMake (e.g. platform ones) and many "Find" scripts dereference non-defined variables and assume that to be legal. E.g. [FindBoost.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBoost.cmake) module checks `Boost_DEBUG` variable in many `if(Boost_DEBUG)` expressions, but doesn't define that variable (the variable could be set by the caller). So, `set -u` behavior, would it exist, would break such CMake scripts.

Comment: There is `cmake --warn-uninitialized`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With version 3.5.x, the new `-Werror=dev` combined with  `--warn-uninitialized` has the behavior I wanted.

So final solution is just to create an alias:

```
alias cmake="cmake -Werror=dev --warn-uninitialized"
```

Answer (score 6):

[As mentioned by KamilCuk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69280810/does-cmake-has-an-option-to-avoid-using-undefined-variables-like-bash-set-u#comment122452698_69280810), there is the [`--warn-uninitialized`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-warn-uninitialized) flag which you can pass when invoking CMake to configure a project. If you want it to be an error, then add [`-Werror=dev`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-Werror).