# SDL doesn't want to be include

Tags: c, sdl

I want to create a little app with SDL.

I got this error

```
C:/usr/CLionProjects/SDL2_basic/main.c:2:10: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <SDL.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

my main.c :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

and my Cmakelist.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(SDL2_basic C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules)

set(SDL2_PATH "C:/SDL2-2.28.5/x86_64-w64-mingw32")

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCULDE_DIR})

add_executable(SDL2_basic main.c)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
```

I excepte a solution to include SDL in my file.

Comment: `SDL2_INCULDE_DIR` seems to be a typo. Fix it and perhaps things work.

Comment: thank for helping blind and dump people.

Comment: Everyone makes typos and doesn't immediately spot them; doesn't make them blind and dumb. Question is: why does cmake not complain about it? I hardly know cmake, so I guess its default is to ignore empty results or similar, but perhaps it has a warning flag for such cases.

Comment: Perhaps [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69280810/does-cmake-has-an-option-to-avoid-using-undefined-variables-like-bash-set-u).

Comment: `set(SDL2_PATH "C:/SDL2-2.28.5/x86_64-w64-mingw32")` remove this line from Cmakelist.txt, drop cmake cache  and try one more time,

Comment: @Chahalor I spend plenty of time here and at work pointing out the obvious that folks can't see in their own code. Those same people point out the obvious to me at times too. Reading your own code with the same critical eye as reading others code isn't easy, but almost everyone I know gets better at it over time. If that typo is the worst thing that happens today then it was a good day! :)